# Выбор оперативной памяти DDR-2

Tags: ram

Здравствуйте.

Хочу поставить на плату **P5ND2SE** которая поддерживает **DDR2 667/533/400 Mhz** новую оперативку.

В данный момент в магазинах есть DDR2 240pin/2GB/**800** Kingston,тоесть **800Mhz**

```
Вопрос, потянет ли материнка?
```

*Прошу прощения за невнятное обьяснение,просто это срочно надо узнать.Знаю что надо в БитКод,но там активность ноль.*

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что к программированию или администрированию отношения не имеет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если частота DDR2 выше чем что дает мать - потянет. Главное чтобы частота оперативки не была ниже той что дает мать

Comment: И еще один вопрос,возможно ли поставить 2 планки по 512 и одну 2гб вместе (2 * 512 + 2048) если у них разные частоты.

Comment: Обычно можно (на данной плате не знаю). Работать все будет по нижней частоте.

Comment: @diRect_Z Без основательного теста в этом нельзя быть уверенным. Я бы **не советовал**, но если надо, то поступил бы так: воткнул бы двухгиговый в первый слот первого банка (скорее всего он желтый на [этой картинке](http://www.nix.ru/autocatalog/motherboards_asustek/59817_top_large.jpg)), 512-е - в черные слоты. Если все это заведется, то нагрузил систему часа на три, после чего прогнал [memtest](http://www.memtest.org). Если ошибок нет, то, в принципе, можно оставлять. Если же они есть, то поменял бы местами черные с желтым и повторил тест.

Comment: Спасибо всем.
Так и поступлю,а лучше не буду эксперементировать, приобрету 2 одинаковые планки.

Comment: @diRect_Z, только учтите, что если у Вас 32-бит Windows-XP SP3, то больше 3Гбайт она не увидит.

Comment: Вообще нет смысла ставить > 2гб оперативки для любой 32x ОС